# UFW won't start with server

Tags: server, ufw

I'm configuring a new server with ubuntu-server. UFW doesn't want to start automatically when server boot.

ufw enable work and start the service but it doesn't restart with a reboot.

Do you any ideas where I can get some logs or debug to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it whether ufw is enabled on startup by following command.

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i ufw
```

You can enable on startup using following command.

```
sudo systemctl enable ufw
```

Comment: It work .. Thanks !!